# Specific Search Terms/Query Entered (NSFW)

Tags: search, query

(Warning: NSFW website. 18+)

The search panel on my company's website seems to be searching for individual words rather than for the query entered.

For example, when I search for o ring 104 products come back in the search results (whereas we sell less than 10 items with the words 'o ring' in the title) (http://rougegarments.co.uk/catalogsearch/result/?q=o+ring)

How would I go about changing this to search for query as opposed to specific terms. I am running the Buyshop ver 2.3.1 Theme in Magento.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Magento default search uses OR to search, so it searches for things containing "o" or "ring".
To make this an AND search, the easiest (yet not cleanest) solution is as follows:

Make a copy of `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/resource/Fulltext.php`
and place it: `app/code/local/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/resource/Fulltext.php`

On about line 356 you will find

```
$likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
```

Change that to:

```
$likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
```

Then about line 378 find

```
$where .= ($where ? ' OR ' : '') . $likeCond;
```

Change that to:

```
$where .= ($where ? ' AND ' : '') . $likeCond;
```

Now, go to the backend and reindex your search index in the indexer section.
Afterwards, your search should be using AND instead of OR search.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found the fulltext.php file in core but the folder CatalogSearch doesn't seem to exist in the local folder?

Comment: @Paul_Rouge You have to create the folders in local!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from Magento Admin

1) `Goto System->Configuration->CATALOG->Catalog->Catalog Search`

2) Make Search Type as either LIKE or Combine(LIKE and FULLTEXT)